# Solution Verification: Find Limit: $\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{3+4i}{15}\right)^n$ n is even, $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}$ n is odd

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I know there is a different solution to this problem. I solved it myself as follows. Was wondering if I solved it correctly or if I made some small mistakes (e.g. simplifying error).

$(s_n) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{3+4i}{15}\right)^n &\text{even }n, \\
\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n} & \text{odd }n.
\end{cases}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}~~~~(n\in\mathbb{N})$.

Case $n$ is even:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{3+4i}{15}\right)^n=\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{3}{15}+\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n=\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n
\end{equation*}

If $a_n\rightarrow a$ and $b_n\rightarrow b$ then $a_n+b_n\rightarrow a+b$.
\begin{equation*}
\text{Define }a_n=\frac{1}{2}~~\text{ and }~~b_n=\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n.
\end{equation*}
Then:
\begin{equation*}
a_n=\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
b_n=\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n}{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n}=\frac{9^{-n}}{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n}=\frac{\frac{1}{9^n}}{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n}\rightarrow\frac{0}{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n}=0
\end{equation*}
Since $a_n\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$ and $b_n\rightarrow0$ then $a_n+b_n\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}+0=\frac{1}{2}$.

Case $n$ is odd:
\begin{multline*}
\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}}\\=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n\cdot(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}})}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}+\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}+\sqrt{1}\right)}\\=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}+\sqrt{1}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}+\sqrt{1}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+0}+\sqrt{1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{multline*}

Comment: I can tell you that your conclusion is correct.

Comment: solution makes sense to me as well, +1

Comment: That seems perfectly reasonable to me. There's a little bit more that would be needed in terms of manipulating epsilons and deltas for it to go through rigorously but it's a perfectly fine motivation. (if you want to do the formal bit it shouldn't be that hard, but it's not really necessary)

Comment: Not buying this: $\frac{\frac{1}{9^n}}{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n}\rightarrow\frac{0}{\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{15}i\right)^n}$.  Can't split a limit into two parts without justification.

Comment: Consider $\frac {(\frac 12)^n}{(\frac 23)^n}\to \frac 0{(\frac 23)^n}= 0$.  Do you buy that?